# ioutil.ReadAll alternative that only consumes data, without duplicating the byte array

Tags: go, io, reader

Called from a `mux.HandleFunc`, I have an `http.Request.FormFile` which is of type `multipart.File`. I'm benchmarking a browser's file upload speed, so I don't need to verify the data. My current code is:

```golang
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
return len(fileBytes)
```

`ioutil.ReadAll` makes an unneeded copy. Is there an alternative method to verify that I have all the data without having to create a copy?

Optionally, what can I replace `len(fileBytes)` with? If this should be in a separate question you may ignore it.

#### What have I tried

`.ReadAll` calls [`readAll`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.14.4/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go#L18) calling [`bytes.Buffer.ReadFrom`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.14.4/src/bytes/buffer.go#L199) calling `io.Reader.Read`, which I can't find.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to copy the content of the file into [`ioutil.Discard`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#Discard) which doesn't store but discards the data. `io.Copy()` copies until EOF is reached (or an error occurs), and returns the number of copied bytes:

```
n, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, file)
```

Comment: Just for completeness (and for the next reader), if the OP were operating on real OS files, they could just [seek](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek) past the unneeded data fragment.

Comment: @kostix Or better, just get the file size / length with `File.Stat()` and `FileInfo.Size()`.